# I want to print odd number using Python

Tags: python

```
count=int(input("insert number")
i=0
while True:
    i+=1
    if i % 2 == 0:
        continue
    print(i)
    if i == count:
        break
```

When I put odd number(5, 7, 9, etc),
This code prints odd number to count.
But When I put even number(2,4,6,8, etc), This code does not stop.
Please give me solution

Comment: Just change `(i == count)` to `(i >= count)`

Comment: Put `if i==count` before `if i%2 ==0`

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA, doesn't that cause the last number to not be printed?

Comment: `for i in range(1, count + 1, 2): print(i)`

Answer (score 0):

That's because it only stops at odd number. since you added continue first when the number is even.
You can do this:

```
count = int(input("insert number"))
i = 0
while True:
    i+=1
    if i % 2 == 0: 
        if i >= count: break #added this
        continue
    print(i)
    if i >= count: #fixed == to >=
        break
```

I fixed `if i == count:` to `if i >= count:` and I added `if i >= count: break` in continue statement because it won't break when it will keep continuing. and it works!

or do this:

```
count = int(input("insert number"))
i = 0
while i != count:
    i+=1
    if i % 2 == 0:
        continue
    print(i)
    if i == count:
        break
```

I added `while i != count:`. that makes if i is same with count it stops!

or just do this:

```
count = int(input("insert number"))
i = 0
for i in range(1, count + 1, 2):
    print(i)
```

I added a for statement like this. -> start at 1 and repeat until count +1 and for every repeat, i + 2.

Answer (score 0):

Will changing the while loop's condition help? Here is a suggestion:

```
def get_count():
    print("insert number")
    count = int(input())
    return count


def main():
    count = get_count()
    i = 0
    while (i != count):
        i+=1
        if i % 2 == 0:
            continue
        print(i)

main()
```